# Fast counting matches between large number of integer arrays

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, cython

I'm wondering whether there are any efficient algorithms to count number of matched integers between large number of integer arrays. The codes in [Cython](https://cython.org/) are as follows.

`match_ints.pyx`

```
cimport cython
from libc.stdlib cimport calloc, free

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

np.import_array()


@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.initializedcheck(False)
cdef void count_matches(int[:, ::1] target_arrays, int[::1] ref_array, int[::1] num_matches):

    cdef:
        Py_ssize_t i, j
        Py_ssize_t n = target_arrays.shape[0]
        Py_ssize_t c = target_arrays.shape[1]
        Py_ssize_t nf = ref_array.shape[0]
        Py_ssize_t m = ref_array[nf - 1] + 5
        int * ind = <int *> calloc(m, sizeof(int))
        int k, g

    for i in range(nf):
        ind[ref_array[i]] = 1

    for i in range(n):
        k = 0
        for j in range(c):
            g = target_arrays[i, j]
            if g < m and ind[g] == 1:
                k += 1
        num_matches[i] = k

    free(ind)


cpdef count_num_matches(int[:, ::1] target_arrays, int[::1] ref_array):

    cdef:
        Py_ssize_t n = target_arrays.shape[0]
        int[::1] num_matches = np.zeros(n, dtype=np.int32)

    count_matches(target_arrays, ref_array, num_matches)

    return np.asarray(num_matches)
```

The idea here is quite simple. For the reference integer array to be matched, it is sorted in ascending order (by `sort` method). An indicator array `ind` is created with the length as the max integer of the reference array (`+5` to avoid indexing out of range), by taking the advantage that integers in the array are not large. So each integer is considered as an index, and corresponding position in `ind` is assigned as 1. Then iterating through every `target_array` to count the number of integers matched in reference array.

During the matches, all integers in `target_arrays` are considered as indexes and matched if the indexes in `ind` are `1`.

Test method is set in `test_main_counts.py`.

```
# test_main_counts.py
from match_ints import count_num_matches
import numpy as np


def count_num_matches_main():
    x = np.random.randint(50, 6000, size=(1000000, 40), dtype=np.int32)
    ref_x = np.random.randint(100, 2500, size=800, dtype=np.int32)

    ref_x.sort()

    return count_num_matches(x, ref_x)


if __name__ == "__main__":
     nums = count_num_matches_main()
     print(nums[:10])
```

The `setup` file.

```
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy as np


setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize(
        "match_ints.pyx",
        compiler_directives={
            "language_level": "3",
        }
    ),
    include_dirs=[
        np.get_include()
    ]
)
```

Because all integers are not large, and there are many duplicates (in my real applications, millions of arrays only contain few thousand unique integers), any relevant algorithms exist to improve this kind of problems by, e.g., taking the advantage of much less unique integers?

Comment: Not sure I get this:  as always its space complexity vs time complexity? Using dicts, integer as key, value as count you can forgoe m_lists times n*log n sorting, and use O(n) inserting. Comparing dicts using unions/diffs based on keys is solved and fast, key lookup is O(1) - getting how many occurences per key is a min(d[key], d2[key]) operation  etc - not sure if that is what you are after.  In reality space vs time is very dependend on your data. for lots of identical ints in your lists the dicts are smallish due to reducing m entries in list to 1 entry in dict. The followup ...

Comment: .. comparisoon on smallish dicts should be fast as well due to few keys to be compared.

Comment: Is  ref_array constant? Are target_arrays constant? Or they all are changed between calls? Your approach takes O(nf * log(nf) + c*n) time, treats target_arrays as fast as possible.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Thanks. I'm thinking in this way too, but not very clear on how to perform this to efficiently parse the results to get a count for each `target_array`. Another thing I'm worrying is that every time Python's type check can reduce the time, which is why I'm using Cython.

Comment: @MBo Actually, the matrix, i.e., `target_arrays` is fixed, and `ref_array` will be varying during running my codes. But `ref_array` can't be preallocated because it is generated from calculations, and the number is again very large. Sorry that these variable names may be confusing at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`target_arrays is fixed` - It is nice!

In this case you can pre-treat target arrays and build a kind of "inverted index" (concept from the field of search engines and databases ). For every possible value create an array of indices of target arrays containing that value like:

```
      inverted[] 
val   target_arrays_containing_val
1     2,5,100, 999999  
2     7, 13, 3141592
...
6000  3,111, 222,444,555,888
```

Now for every element from `ref_arr` increment counters for corresponding arrays

```
for x in ref_arr:
   for a in inverted[x]:
       num_matches[a] += 1
```

For rather short target arrays (40 in your example) sublists of `inverted[]` should be quite short, and you'll get significant gain: from current dominating `O(n*c)` complexity to `O(nf*mean_sublist_size)`

Plain Python implementation.
I get rid off duplicates in `targets`, but don't treat them in `ref` for simplicity.

```
import random

targ = [[random.randint(1,50) for i in range(6)] for j in range(10)]
ref = [random.randint(1,30) for i in range(15)]

mx = max([max(x) for x in targ])
inverted = [[] for i in range(mx+1)]
num_matches = [0]*len(targ)
for ind, x in enumerate(targ):
    for val in x:
        if not (ind in inverted[val]):
            inverted[val].append(ind)    

for x in ref:
   for a in inverted[x]:
       num_matches[a] += 1

for x in targ:
    print(x)
print()
print(inverted)
print(ref)
print(num_matches)

>>>>
[39, 27, 30, 31, 12, 45]
[45, 45, 36, 16, 33, 10]
[32, 34, 48, 35, 36, 36]
[18, 16, 6, 19, 1, 35]
[32, 13, 1, 2, 30, 34]
[40, 18, 37, 18, 25, 47]
[21, 27, 33, 42, 43, 2]
[22, 47, 2, 34, 25, 26]
[30, 47, 6, 23, 39, 44]
[21, 43, 27, 1, 12, 30]

[[], [3, 4, 9], [4, 6, 7], [], [], [], [3, 8], [], [], [], [1], [],
 [0, 9], [4], [], [], [1, 3], [], [3, 5], [3], [], [6, 9], [7], [8],
 [], [5, 7], [7], [0, 6, 9], [], [], [0, 4, 8, 9], [0], [2, 4], [1, 6], 
 [2, 4, 7], [2, 3], [1, 2], [5], [], [0, 8], [5], [], [6], [6, 9], [8], 
 [0, 1], [], [5, 7, 8], [2]]

[15, 8, 22, 18, 15, 24, 16, 22, 30, 30, 27, 18, 9, 22, 17]

[3, 1, 0, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3]
```

Comment: The idea "inverted index" is great. After appropriate organising the data structure, the calculation achieved more than 10x faster.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comment, count stuff into dicts, use set operations on dict.keys() to find common/eleminate unique keys from the result dict that has the minimal occurences.

You can avoid sorting + traversing by just traversing when building the dicts. By using a set of "seen_keys" so far you can ignore values of later lists that have not yet been seen:

```
'''This is plain python - working code as guideline - you would have to transform that 
to cpython/numpy yourself'''
# millions of arrays with small amount of unique ints in it
l1 = [1,1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3,3,3, 4,4,4,4,4,4, 99] 
l2 = [1,1,1,1,1,   2,2,2,2,2,   3,3,3,3,3,   4,4,4,4,4,   98]
l3 = [1,           2,2,         3,3,3]

dicts = []
seen_keys = set(l1) # initial keys from one list, doesn't matter which

# m lists: go once through each list  m times O(n)
for l in [l1,l2,l3]:   # m lists result in m dicts
    curr_d = {} 
    dicts.append(curr_d)

    # o(n) with n=len(list) instead of sorting with O(n*log(n))
    for i in l:
        if i not in seen_keys: continue  # skipable -> missing in ealier list
        # in plain python you can use defaultdict(int) or Counter for speedups
        curr_d.setdefault(i,0) 
        curr_d[i] += 1

# resulting dict for minimal counts of keys that are in ALL lists
total_d = {}
for d in dicts:
    # initial values 
    if not total_d:
        total_d = dict(d.items())
        continue

    # remove all things from total_d that are not in new dict
    # this will reduce runtimes the further you go as the next step has fewer updates
    diffr = total_d.keys() - d.keys()
    for remove in diffr:
        del total_d[remove]

    # reduce count to minial for any key that is in total_d and new dict
    commn =  total_d.keys() & d.keys()
    for c in commn:
        total_d[c] = min(total_d[c],d[c])  # ternary maybe faster

print(total_d) #    total_d.su
```

Outputs:

```
{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}
```